# How to plot the three value based draw the quadratic curve?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```html
<!doctype>
<html>
<head>
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="rickshawmmm/src/css/graph.css">
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="rickshawmmm/examples/css/lines.css">

<script src="rickshawmmm/vendor/d3.v3.js"></script>

<script src="rickshawmmm/rickshaw.js"></script>

<style>
#chart {
 position: relative;
 left: 40px;
}
#y_axis {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 width: 40px;
}
#x_axis {
 position: relative;
 left: 40px;
 height: 40px;
}


</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="chart_container">
 <div id="y_axis"></div>
 <div id="chart"></div>
 <div id="x_axis"></div>
</div>

<div>
 <button onclick="window.showTextOnOtherSide()">Change text location</button>
 <button onclick="window.setSize()">setSize()</button>
</div>

<script>

// instantiate our graph!

var graph = new Rickshaw.Graph( {
 element: document.getElementById("chart"),
 renderer: 'line',
 height: 300,
 width: 800,
 series: [
  {
   data: [ { x: 0, y: 800 }, { x: 1, y: 200 }, { x: 2, y: 800 }, { x: 3, y: 70 }, { x: 4, y: 32 } ],
   color: "#c05020"
  }, 
 ]
} );

var y_ticks = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.Y( {
 graph: graph,
 orientation: 'left',
 tickFormat: Rickshaw.Fixtures.Number.formatKMBT,
 element: document.getElementById('y_axis')
} );

graph.render();

window.showTextOnOtherSide = function() {
 y_ticks.orientation = y_ticks.orientation === 'right' ? 'left' : 'right';
 graph.render();
};

window.setSize = function() {
 var width = parseInt(prompt('New axis width?', y_ticks.width), 10);
 var height = parseInt(prompt('New axis height?', y_ticks.height), 10);
 y_ticks.setSize({
  width: width,
  height: height
 });
};
var format = function(n) {

 var map = {
  0: 'zero',
  1: 'first',
  2: 'second',
  3: 'third',
  4: 'fourth'
 };

 return map[n];
}

var x_ticks = new Rickshaw.Graph.Axis.X( {
 graph: graph,
 orientation: 'bottom',
 element: document.getElementById('x_axis'),
 pixelsPerTick: 200,
 tickFormat: format
} );
graph.render();
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I have some code i am try to draw the curve in array method but i want to how to draw the curve in quadratic based on three value for example 5x^2+8x-6 ;a=5,b=8,c=-6 in the three value based how to draw the quadratic equation please help me.

Comment: You know `y = 5x^2+8x-6 `?

Comment: quadratic equation using to plot the graph.for example in that equation 5x^2+8x-6  for ax2+bx+c formula method